# How to pass a select value to multiple servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am new to JSP, and have a question as below.

In servlet1, I can use request.getParameter() to get the value to SELECT var1.

```
String ciStr = request.getParameter("var1")
```

But is there any way I can get the SELECT var1 from servlet2?

Thanks.

JSP code

```
<form action="Servlet1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Confidence Interval
        <SELECT name="var1" >
                <OPTION value="ci99">99%</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="ci95">95%</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="ci90">90%</OPTION>
        </SELECT> <br>
        <textarea name="textArea1" style="width:500px;height:150px;"></textarea> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" size="20" />
    </form>

 <form action="Servlet2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Confidence Interval
            <SELECT name="var2" >
                    <OPTION value="ci99">99%</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="ci95">95%</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="ci90">90%</OPTION>
            </SELECT> <br>
            <textarea name=textArea2" style="width:500px;height:150px;"></textarea> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" size="20" />
        </form>
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: No. with `<form>` only the inputs WITHIN that particular form get submitted. you'd need JS to copy things around on the client-side to get stuff from the servlet2 form to be visible to whatever's handling servlet1

Comment: Its not clear what you're trying to do.  Also, you CANNOT use `request.getParameter()` at all because you set the form as `enctype="multipart/form-data"` (which will make `request.getParameter()` always return `null`). You don't need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` unless you're uploading files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use HttpSession object to set the value over server and then get these value any where on server.

```
HttpSession hs=request.getSession();
```

and you can set the value with a unique name .

```
hs.setAttribute("name","value");
```

and get any where on server by use the name.

```
String var=(String)hs.getAttribute("name");
```